# Ctrl-Enter, Shift-Enter and Enter are interpreted as the same key

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, input-method, ibus

I'm using Fedora 30 with KDE and am trying to bind (Zsh) `autosuggest-execute` to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> for convenience. I'm trying to get it to work in `gnome-terminal`.

However I discovered that `showkey -a` always returns `^M` in these three cases: <kbd>Enter</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>, and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

I tried this [method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45714460/2519977) (`Ctrl <Return> : "\033M"` in `.XCompose`), but it didn't work at all as the XCompose file wasn't being read. So I decided to install `ibus` as it is [not shipped with my KDE install](https://pagure.io/fedora-kickstarts/blob/master/f/fedora-kde-minimization.ks#_3) with `dnf groupinstall input-methods`.

Running `ìbus-setup` gets me this warning now:

```
GTK+ supports to output one char only: "\033M": ! Ctrl <Return> : "\033M"
```

Unfortunately all enter combinations still boil down to `^M` in `gnome-terminal` as well as `xterm`.

Is there a way to differentiate between those key combinations with or without ibus?

Comment: FWIW, the "string" in `.XCompose` can only be a single (possibly multi-byte) character. I don't see how that "\033M" could've ever worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to install ibus, etc. All X11 apps have access to the exact keycodes *and* to their xkb / xim translations, and may *ignore* the latter.

The problem is in the terminal emulator, and with the fact that there's no standard way to represent key combos like Ctrl-Enter in the terminal. Also, each terminal emulator has (or hasn't) its own way of configuring key-bindings.

In `xterm`, like in any xt-based app you can easily configure it with X11 resources. For instance, this will translate Ctrl-Enter to the escape corresponding to the `F33` function key (according to `infocmp`):

```
xterm -xrm '*VT100*translations: #override Ctrl<Key>Return:string("\033[20;5~")'
```

Then you could bind that `\e[20;5~` to whatever action you want in readline's `~/.inputrc`, with `bind` in `bash`, with `bindkey` in `zsh`, etc.

X11 resources are stored as the `RESOURCE_MANAGER` property of the root window and can be loaded there with the `xrdb` utility; usually, `xrdb` will be called from an x11 session initialization script to load the content of the `~/.Xresources` file.

KDE or Gnome applications like `konsole` and `gnome-terminal` have their own way of configuring key combos to actions; I don't know if that includes the ability to write arbitrary strings to the pseudo-tty master.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I was able to get it half-working in `konsole`. `Ctrl`-`Enter` now translates to `\e[20;5~`, but bindkey doesn't work for some reason. I'm using `bindkey '\e[20;5~' forward-word`. As of now, it just outputs `\e[20;5~` when pressing the combination. I was hoping to get it working in `gnome-terminal` as well, but `Konsole` may be a viable alternative.

Comment: `bindkey '\e[20;5~' forward-word` works for me. Maybe konsole is sending literally `\ ` + `e` instead of Esc (ascii 0x1f)? Also, if you're using vi keys in zsh, you'll have to use `bindkey -a ...` to do the binding in "command mode".

Comment: Yes, that was the problem, thanks! `konsole` needs a capital `e` in order for it to be escape: `\E[20;5~`.

Comment: ESC is ascii 0x1b, not 0x1f, sorry ;-)

Answer (score 0):

This is how to set it up in `konsole`:

Also see the [Kde Reference for Key Bindings in Konsole](https://docs.kde.org/stable5/en/applications/konsole/key-bindings.html).

Settings -> Edit Current Profile -> Keyboard -> (select used keyboard layout) -> Edit -> Search/Filter for `Return`.

**Edit the following entries (left column only):**

- Change `Return-Shift-NewLine` to `Return-Shift-Ctrl-NewLine`
- Change `Return-Shift+NewLine` to `Return-Shift-Ctrl+NewLine`

This allows to differentiate between `Enter` and `Ctrl` + `Enter`.

**Add the following entry:**

`Return+Ctrl` -> `\E[20;5~`

Now just add `bindkey '\e[20;5~' autosuggest-execute` or any other sink in `~/.zshrc`.